# Cannot open port 1433 for Azure SQL database in Mac

Tags: java, sql-server, macos, azure

I'm trying to access a Azure-hosted SQL database on my java application. I checked the port 1433 using nmap and it shows that it's closed:

```
Starting Nmap 7.12 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-09-02 09:44 PHT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00014s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
1433/tcp closed ms-sql-s
```

I have edited the /etc/pf.conf and restarted my mac but the port is still closed. Here is my pf.conf:

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
pass in proto tcp from any to any port 1433
```

Also, my firewall is set to off.

My java app is throwing this error:

```
Error starting database: The TCP/IP connection to the host flowengine7.database.windows.net, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection timed out: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

Java code:

```
 String connectionString =
                "jdbc:sqlserver://dbName.database.windows.net:1433;database=dbName;user=user@@user;password=passwordhere;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";

        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
            println 'connected';
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (connection != null) try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question to show your actual Java code you're using to connect with SQL Database service. Also: Have you added your IP address to your SQL Database server's IP list?

Comment: I added my java code and I've already added my ip to the whitelist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overlooking the Azure SQL **server-level Firewall**:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/

[image: firewall-entry]

You need to whilelist your Mac's Public IP address in there to be able to connect from local. By default only Azure services can reach 1433/TCP on your Azure SQL instance (permitted by **Allow access to Azure Services** setting in the Azure SQL Firewall).

If you're getting a new Public IP address every time you reboot your DSL/Cable/Fiber modem you'll need to define a whole range of addresses not just the one (i.e. **174.73.0.0 - 174.73.255.255** vs. listing **174.73.16.180**). Hopefully you'll always grab an IP address in the same range.

Comment: I've already added my public ip but I'm getting the same error

Comment: Since `nmap` is telling you the port is __closed__, double check the Public IP address and make sure you're not being filtered outbound by your firewall/router/whathaveyou..