# Can I use: MyWebSQL with an AZURE SQL database?

Tags: php, sql, azure

I'm trying to get web access to my windows azure sql database (since the default web interface seems to be dropped).

Now I installed MyWebSQL and it looks like I'm connected to my host, but the page that follows is blank.

I edited the servers.php file and added the following code to the list:

```
'AZURE SQL' => array(
                  'host'     => 'ukwxkawvg1.database.windows.net',
                  'driver'   => 'sql'
               ),
```

What am I missing and is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

If it can connect to a "classic" Microsoft SQL Server, it should also work with Azure SQL.

Make sure you have the Public IP address of your MyWebSQL's server whitelisted with Azure SQL Firewall. See my other answer here on how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39310428/4148708

I would also turn on PHP error logging for MyWebSQL. Maybe that white page is not that white with errors turned on.

Comment: "Simplified Database Web Administration. For MySQL, SQLite and PostgreSQL databases." Does this include the Azure SQL? My IP is whitelisted and the php error log turned one does also give a blank page.

Comment: It doesn't. MS SQL folks use this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx -- "This version of SSMS works with all supported versions of SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 - SQL Server 2016), and provides the greatest level of support for working with the latest cloud features in Azure SQL Database."

Comment: I'll have a look into that!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it isn't possible and I've got to use SSMS.

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)